# Stats or Date Histogram query for unindexed fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following document structure

```
{
  "@timestamp": DDMMYYHHMMSS,
  "title": "some test here",
  "views": 4
}
```

and my mapping is

```
mappings: {

  _default_: {

  _all: {
    enabled: false
  }
}

mytype: {
  dynamic: "strict"

_all: {
  enabled: false
}

properties: {

@timestamp: {
  type: "date"
  format: "dateOptionalTime"
}

title: {
  type: "string"
}

    views: {
      type: "integer"
      index: "no"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically I don't want to index my views field as I don't want to search by views, but I want to get stats for this field or get a date histogram, for example a histogram of the total views over a given time per hour or per day

My query looks like this

```
{
  "facets": {
    "0": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "key_field": "@timestamp",
        "value_field": "views",
        "interval": "1y"
      },
      "global": true,
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match_all": {}
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

This returns

```
facets: {
-
0: {
_type: "date_histogram"
-
entries: [
-
{
time: 1356998400000
count: 27339
min: "Infinity"
max: "-Infinity"
total: 0
total_count: 0
mean: 0
}
]
}
}
```

So my question is can I do facet/aggregation queries on fields that are not indexed? And if not why not? Isn't indexing supposed to be only for searching?

Thanks